# Odd enum memory issue in layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management, layoutsubviews

In the layoutSubviews of uitableviewcell, there is logics like

```
switch(enum_instance){ }
```

enum_instance was changed from some place, for instance in one timer, then setNeedLayout to trigger layoutSubviews

But the enum_instance in layoutSubviews will not be updated. Is this bug ? or something wrong I have done ?

Thanks,

Comment: `setNeedLayout` will only schedule redraw for new cycle. Calling `layoutIfNeeded` will lays out the subviews immediately.

Comment: actually I am using layoutIfNeeded :)  the local variable will be updated as unexpected sometimes, that is odd

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `UITableViewCell`s are recycled. Scrolling `tableView` will shuffle cells when `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is called. This means that `layoutIfNeeded` my be called on wrong cell (after scrolling, that cell may be assigned to another `indexPath`). Only secure place to setup cell property is in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` where cell should be configured.

Simpler way is to recalculate cell within `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This methods can be re-triggered by calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` providing array of `indexPath`s for cells that you want to redraw.